# How to dicard GET values in show method (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

In my `ClientController@index`, I have a form with a select input to list every client in the database.

After submitting the form to list detailed client information, the `URL` is like `/clients?client_id=id`.

The routes are the defult with `route::resource()`.

```
<form name="show_client" id="show_client">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="branch"><b>Selectione o Cliente</b></label>
          <select class="form-control select2" name="client_id" id="client_id" required>
              <option value="">Selecione o Cliente</option>
              @foreach ($list as $client)
                  <option value="{{ $client->client_id }}">{{ $client->name }} </option>
              @endforeach
           </select>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded">Listar Cliente</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
          $(function() {
           $('#show_client').submit(function(){
             var client_id = $('#client_id').val();
             $(this).attr('action', "/clients/" + client_id);
           });
          });
</script>
```

Is there any way to work the url to be /clients/id?

I accomplish that by using an js function but it's clearly not the solution.

Comment: Can't you just list your `$client` as `<a>` elements, and do something like `<a href="{{ url('/clients/'.$client->id) }}">{{ $client->name }}</a>`? That way, there's no `<select>` and `submit` required; it's just a direct link to the Client.

Comment: if you are using resource routing then the url for the show route is `clients/{client}`, so it is expecting a parameter for the id already.

Comment: Hello @tim, since I have a select, I need to have a form.. I cant list a table for every client and list an <a>.. Im freaking out with this problem...

Comment: @lagbox hello! The problem is, with a Get form, the inputs will go to the url...

Comment: *"I need to have a form"* - Well no, this is **your code**... You're not locked into having a `<form>` with a `<select>`; there are multiple approaches. You could have a table, with pagination, front-end or server-side searching, etc. that lists your clients and provides a link to `/client/{{ $client->id }}`. This approach with the `<select>` still has the issue of loading all your clients into that element, which can be very expensive memory/resource wise. But if you're not open to different approaches, then that's fine. Try `window.location = "/clients/" + client_id;`. Should redirect.

Comment: Hello @TimLewis, I got your point, I will think on listing every client in a datatable. In this way I can use the search filter. Thank you for mind refreshing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to the change event on the select list:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#client_id').change(function(){
        var client_id = $(this).val();
        $('#show_client').attr('action', "/clients/" + client_id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know you can make the parameter in the route optional. That way, it can accept the route without a parameter. You then append the parameter on submit of the form